# How to run and debug multi-file multi-library project in vscode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, makefile, cmake, project

Lets consider a project, with a following structure:

```
project
--main
  --fileX.h
  --fileX.cpp
  --main.cpp // only file, that guranteed to have main()
--libA
  --libA.h
  --fileX.cpp
  --fileY.cpp If they are outdated/not built - build them first
--libB
  --libB.h
  --fileZ.cpp
  --fileW.cpp
```

Pretty simple, also lets consider that project must include and link something standart, like OpenGL lib.

On windows, where I came from, there is Visual Studio, and everything was extremely easy and in some kind of "standart" way:

- You create solution `project`. This is like a root, which just incorporates projects, in a single tree
- You create projects: `main` of type `"binary"` and a couple of libs `libA`, `libB` of `"library"` types (static or dynamic, whatever you require to). That will tell build system how should it glue them together
- You edit `main` settings:

  - Add external include and lib names, and paths
  - Add dependencies. `main` requires `libA` and `libB`. That is simultaneously a hint on build order, plus a linkage hint
- You add files here and there, code it all, make any changes.
- Press debug/run and enjoy. Build system would (re)compile only nesesary files, and link everything needed

Everything involves less than 100 actions, I mean keystrokes and mouse clicks.
VS Commutiny IDE is totally free to use (so no "Use that cool paid IDE" offers could be made in comments and answers)

Now the question. I've installed Ubuntu and vscode, and I am running into wall, trying to setup same project. What actions should be done, so I am able to change any source file in the project, press F5 (Debug), and it would compile and run with same build setup and speed efficiency?

What I've considered?

- Makefile: almost same as writing your own shell script. It's like you have to learn whole new language to do small pretty-standart task - build a project. High leven of entrance, to be good at it.
- vscode launch.json/tasks.json - another language, with examples availble to compile only single file: main.cpp (or just active file). Hard to create manually, requires good knowledge of internal "env" variables
- CMake - another new programming language, different from all others, don't even know how to make vscode and Cmake friends

How a beginner should start C++ debuging with a multi-lib project, without having to waste time maintain that infinite complex build systems?

Comment: There is no other way in VSCode then to use Make or CMake. You can have a look at kDevelop if this is able to create the Make file for you like VS. Yes VS is a GUI for building the Makefile. And the Makefile syntax is not that complex

Comment: You need 4 `Makefile` files. One in the project directory that make-calls the other 3 makefiles in the subdirectories. You can specify that it should make-call the libs first, main.exe depends on the lib.so/.a files. VS uses MSBuild, have you ever looked at that syntax, you are glad that there is a GUI editor for that.

Comment: @rioV8 where can I take default `Makefile` example? Task is pretty simple across every thing you build - You take source files, and, if output is cached(exists) and not outdated - you use it. Otherwise - you compile what was changed, and re-link to a library or binary. Where is such standart makefile example? Or why could one want to use another one, to compile project?

Comment: Search for `GNU make example`. ??cached?? for Makefiles?

Comment: What you need - is a filelist, that is normally maintained by IDE, or it could be just all CPP files. And a hint, what should folder compile to (static lib/dynamic lib/bin) and order of compilation and linkage. This is pretty standart and very straightforward process, that mathematically almost cant be expressed in another way..

Comment: @rioV8 imagine you have big project. If you change a line in a small single file - rebuild will be lightning fast. Where is `Makefile` that implements that standart build process, as I described above?

Comment: @rioV8 Makefile is more like a script, but not a build system. For example I tried `g++ -g $(find -type f -iregex '.*\.cpp')` but it seems to compile every file every time, but not those that changed. It's slow every time and not effective

Comment: @rioV8 okay, analogies. for windows it is msbuild , and for linux it's... what? what is linux standart, easy-to-tweak (no need for shell scripting) convenient build system? - set up file list once in ide, set up dependencies, press build - it build fast (with all caching speedy things)

Comment: a text editor and `Makefile` files and the command `make` or CMake or autoconf. Makefile is not a shell script, or use Qt, no need to use the Qt GUI just use `Qt Creator` and `qmake`

Comment: @rioV8 `Makefile`'s scope is a "bit" wider. It could do system installation, it could be portable across distributions.. Swiss army knife (I think you may even play music, or watch videos with makefile). What I want - is a convenient unix-styled **build tool**, that is focused towards fast semiautomatic setup and provide fast rebuilds, for developement/debug, with no need maintaining file lists in makefile.. With little configuration options (it could involve "run script before/after build" extra settings). In other words, I'd like msbuild for linux. It cant deploy, and was not supposed to.